# Как сохранить xml документ в sql на c#

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Можно ли сохранить xml документ в ячейку sql чтобы при необходимости скачать его в файл. Если можно то как? И желательно с примерами.(я только знакомлюсь с C#).

Comment: для начала вопрос, что за ячейка, какого типа?

Comment: вот это читали: [Примеры массового импорта и экспорта XML-документов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms191184(v=sql.120).aspx)? Также советую ознакомиться: [Import data from XML to SQL Server tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630242/import-data-from-xml-to-sql-server-tables)

Comment: Насколько я понял, Вы хотите хранить XML-документы в базе данных. Помимо того, что я Вам сбросил, можно вместо этого попробовать сделать таблицу с двумя основными столбцами: массив байт считанный из файла и имя файла. И просто стандартными средствами считываем файл и пишем в базу. При необходимости считываем из базы и восстанавливаем документ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала, надо определиться с используемой схемой БД для хранения. А для этого надо ответить на вопрос "откуда XML вообще берется"?

Если документ может загружаться в базу пользователем - то лучше всего подойти к вопросу его хранения как к хранению любого файла - то есть хранить его в `varbinary(max)`, плюс отдельной колонкой имя файла в виде строки, плюс колонки для хранения атрибутов файла, вроде даты создания / изменения.

Если XML формируется внутри программы - то лучше всего сохранять его в `nvarchar(max)`, чтобы не создавать самому себе проблемы с кодировками.

---

Как сохранять данные в БД, я надеюсь, автор разберется сам. Но перед тем, как их туда сохранять - надо их сначала получить.

Преобразовать XML-документ в строку довольно просто:

```
XmlDocument doc = ...;
var xmlstr = doc.OuterXml;

XDocument doc = ...;
var xmlstr = doc.ToString();
```

Однако, обычно нет смысла хранить в виде строки весь документ целиком - достаточно хранить его корневой элемент:

```
XmlDocument doc = ...;
var xmlstr = doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml;

XDocument doc = ...;
var xmlstr = doc.Root.ToString();
```

Второй способ "обрежет" обычно легко восстановимые XML-декларации. На обратное преобразование это никак не повлияет, поскольку корневой элемент остается сам по себе корректным документом.

Если же вы приняли решение хранить документ в виде массива байт - все становится несильно сложнее:

```
XmlDocument doc = ...;
var ms = new MemoryStream();
doc.Save(ms);
var bytes = ms.ToArray();

XDocument doc = ...;
var ms = new MemoryStream();
doc.Save(ms);
var bytes = ms.ToArray();
```

Если есть необходимость указать конкретную кодировку - можно надо использовать `StreamWriter`:

```
XmlDocument doc = ...;
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.ВашаКодировка))
  doc.Save(ms);
var bytes = ms.ToArray();

XDocument doc = ...;
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.ВашаКодировка))
  doc.Save(ms);
var bytes = ms.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ:

1. Сделать столбец для хранения типа nvarchar(MAX).
2. Конвертировать xml-файл в string.

Код:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
                 "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
            "</book>");
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
string str = root.OuterXml;
```

3. Вставить данную строку в БД (зависит от того как работаете с данными)

Недостатком данного способа является то, что такой xml будет "мертвыми данными" с которыми можно будет работать только на клиенте. Гораздо лучше буде задать тип для столбца XML (если таковой поддерживается вашей БД -- например MS SQL и MySQL), тогда с ним можно будет работать и на сервере, но это отдельная очень широкая тема, которая к тому же зависит от вашей БД.

**Дополнительно:**

1. [XmlNode.OuterXml Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx)
2. [xml (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/library/ms187339.aspx)

Comment: Мне кажется не совсем корректно хранить в типе данных `nvarchar(MAX)`. Строки без ограничения часто приводят к проблемам. Как быть с кодировкой? Вам так не кажется?

Comment: В принципе правильно, но есть нюанс: такой способ работает независимо от конкретной БД, имя файла и кодировку можно хранить в отдельных полях, nvarchar(MAX) можно в принципе ограничить, если заранее известно максимальный размер файла. Кроме того в прошлом вопросе ТС использовал вообще varbinary(MAX), что уже вообще плохо. А так да тип XML (со схемой) конечно лучше, но работать будет только с конкретной БД.